# How to configure Archive folder for Outlook in iOS Mail

Tags: mail.app, email, ms-office, archive

I have an Office 365 email account configured as an Exchange account on my iPhone with iOS 13.
When I archive an email, it is moved into the "Archive" folder (in English) even if my account is configured in Italian so that the official archive folder is spelled "Archivio" in Outlook. Everytime I archive an email on iPhone, the English folder is created and the email is moved there.
How do I configure where to archive the email (eg: the right name of the archive folder)?
Thank you.

Comment: Have you set up, Italian language in your Office 365 email account too (from OWA)? I guess, if you open your official email from a web browser, and set the default language to Italian, then it should work in iOS as I have also different language?

Comment: Thank you, I have checked and the service is configured in Italian; the archive folder is used with the right name in Outlook for Windows and in OWA, but not on the iPhone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is a function of Exchange, not the Mail.app or macOS.

The Exchange server is looking for a folder called "Archive" on the server itself so when you rename the folder, it can't find it so it creates a new one.  Then Mail syncs with the Exchange server bringing the "Archive" folder back.

You'll have to file a bug report with Microsoft or just tolerate the English spelling of "Archivio."

Comment: Thank you. It would be a very useful suggestion, except that Outlook wants the Italian spelling, and so I get two different folders. I'll file the bug.

Comment: I believe the bug should also belong to iOS and Apple side. Neither allow archive folder to be configurable.

Comment: Please note that it is not only a spelling problem, it is a behaviour problem: Mail will archive messages under its folder while Outlook will use the other one. Unless you "move" the message manually to the folder you want instead of using the "Archive" button, of course.